# How to create and delete data from entity relationship many-to-many in CRM 2011?

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

How to create and delete data from entity relationship many-to-many in crm 2011?

Code:

```
QueryExpression qry = new QueryExpression();
qry.EntityName = "entity1_entity2";
qry.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

var re = crmservice.RetrieveMultiple(qry).Entities;


crmservice.Delete("entity1_entity2", re[0].Id);
```

FaultException: `The 'Delete' method does not support entities of type 'entity1_entity2'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to link two records via a N:N relationship, you have to use the [Associate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.associaterequest.aspx)/[Disassociate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.disassociaterequest.aspx) request or the corresponding methods of the service proxy.

This will create/delete the corresponding record of the entity1_entity2 entity.

Answer (score 5):

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
...
// get the crm service
...
AssociateEntitiesRequest fooToBar = new AssociateEntitiesRequest
{
    Moniker1 = foo,                // foo is an entity reference
    Moniker2 = bar,                // bar is an entity reference
    RelationshipName = "foo_bar",  // name of the relationship
}

service.Execute(fooToBar)          // relates foo and bar
```

Here's a blog post: http://charithrajapaksha.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-many-to-many-records-in-crm.html

Answer (score 3):

For Delete you try below

```
        // Create an AssociateEntities request.
        //Namespace is Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages
        DisassociateEntitiesRequest request = new DisassociateEntitiesRequest();

        // Set the ID of Moniker1 to the ID of the lead.
        request.Moniker1 = new EntityReference
        {
            Id = moniker1.Id,
            LogicalName = moniker1.Name
        };

        // Set the ID of Moniker2 to the ID of the contact.
        request.Moniker2 = new EntityReference
        {
            Id = moniker2.Id,
            LogicalName = moniker2.Name
        };

        // Set the relationship name to associate on.
        request.RelationshipName = strEntityRelationshipName;

        // Execute the request.
        service.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

In N:N Relationships the records should be associated and disassociated. you can't create and delete records in N:N Relationship. you can use AssociateRequest, DisassociateRequest classes or you can use Associate, Disassociate Messages in Plugin Registration tool.