# How to retrieve all Opportunity Products for the specific Opportunity through c#?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have the Opportunity as shown in the below image:

[image: Opportunity with sub items]

Yesterday, I posted a question on how to create the Opportunity Products (Motor Products) & Dave provided me an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283483/how-do-i-add-items-in-the-sub-menu-options-through-c-sharp-dynamics-crm-online/45284443#45284443) on how to achieve this.

Now, my requirement has been extended to delete these existing Motor Products & add new products.

I'm thinking to do this by first retrieving all the relative Motor Products from this opportunity.

For creating Opportunity Product I used the below code:

```
var opportunityProduct = new Entity(entityMotorName);
opportunityProduct["tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid"] = new EntityReference("opportunity", Guid("opportunityid"));
var opportunityProductId = crmService.Create(opportunityProduct);
```

But, I'm stuck here for retrieing these Motor Products. Once I get the Motor Products which is related to this opportunity I can use the below query.

```
crmService.Delete(entityName,Guid);
```

*Note: my opportunity has opportunityid but no tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid & my Motor Product (opportunityproduct) doesn't have opportunityid but has tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid.*

**Only problem is how to retrieve these Motor Products?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and delete data from entity relationship many-to-many in CRM 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802802/how-to-create-and-delete-data-from-entity-relationship-many-to-many-in-crm-2011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class App
{
    private IOrganizationService svc;

    public App(IOrganizationService svc)
    {
        this.svc = svc;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var list = OppProducts(svc, new Guid("628CF01A-AED1-E411-80EF-C4346BAC7BE8"));
        DeleteList(svc, list);
    }

    public List<Entity> OppProducts(IOrganizationService svc, Guid OppId)
    {
        var query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "opportunityproduct",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid", "opportunityproductid"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression
                    {
                        AttributeName = "tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = { OppId }
                    }   
                }
            }
        };

        var result = svc.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        return result.Entities.ToList();
    }

    public void DeleteList(IOrganizationService svc, List<Entity> list)
    {
        list.ForEach(e => svc.Delete(e.LogicalName, e.Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aron but the main problem here is my opportunityproduct "Motor Products" doesn't have the attribute opportunityid. That is the reason it was difficult in retrieving the Motor Products using the existing MSDN samples. Could you suggest any other way.

Comment: OK, substituting "tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid" for "opportunityid" should do the trick, and I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Aron, please refer the note in my question. there is no tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid in my opportunity. Thats the main issue.

Comment: That's fine. If you pass the Opportunity's GUID into the OppProducts method, it will match the Opp Product's tmeic_opportunitymotorproductid to that ID. And not that it matters programmatically, but why is the system using a new field for the opportunity's foreign key rather than the out-of-box one?

Comment: Yes Aron, Thank you very much. It worked. Thanks a lot again.